# Trouble connecting css and js to zend framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, zend-framework2

I have successfully connected **css** and **js** to **zendframework** using the following code in my one project, but this exact same code does not work in my other project. CSS and JS files are in the correct directories. I am coding after almost a year in this framework. So I don't know where i am messing it up

JS

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()
    ->prependFile($this->basePath('js/jquery.min.js')) ?>
```

CSS

```
<?php echo $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'))

        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css'))
```

This connection of css and js files in taking place in layout.phtml

[image: This is how it is supposed to look]

This is how it is supposed to be:

[image: This is how it looks]

This is how it looks now

Comment: i have mentioned less js and css files in question, so that i look more clear

Comment: Define "does not work" - what happens?

Comment: All html code is loaded in page but no affect of js or css on the page. i al gonna add some snap shots that how it looks and must it look. hope that would help to answer it

Comment: And if you view the js/css in your browser files directly, do they load? This doesn't sound like a ZF problem.

Comment: Open your browser console network and check if they are loaded.

Comment: thank u very much for asking me check console guys, the css files are not loaded and are failed to load in console. So this means something is wrong with css files

Comment: again thank u guys. problem is solved. i was loading wrong files with correct names. i just put correct files of css in their respective directories and the problem is solved